# Customizing Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

[image]

I always click on the header part of Thunderbird which annoys me a lot. Because the top e mail I received is on top row, sometimes I click on "From" or "Subject" and then all the mail is sorted according to that.

Can I lock these parts so they do not sort any more?

Also E mail rows are too small. Can I make them bigger? And even maybe everything on the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change Thunderbird's font sizes to suit.  It's not as simple as you might think though: [Pane and menu fonts](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Pane_and_menu_fonts)